# How to make strcmp to return 0 in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, strcmp

I want the call to the strcmp function to return 0, which means

```
int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
```

`const char *s1` and `const char *s2` should contain the same string. If `s2` points to the string "hello" and `n` is 4, how can I pass to `s1` a decimal value that will also correspond to `hello`?

```
 8049e87:       c7 44 24 08 04 00 00    movl   $0x4,0x8(%esp) // 4
 8049e8e:       00
 8049e8f:       c7 44 24 04 80 bd 04    movl   $0x804bd80,0x4(%esp) // the constant is "hello"
 8049e96:       08 
 8049e97:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp) // The contents of %eax are a decimal (%d)
 8049e9a:       e8 61 ec ff ff          call   8048b00 <strncmp@plt>
 8049e9f:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax // I want this to be 0!
```

I tried passing in the decimal value for "h" in ASCII, and it seemed to be the right direction, but not fully.

Comment: `eax` needs to contain the address of a string, not a "decimal" value

Comment: Following that line of thought, I tried passing in the decimal value of the 0x804bd80 (so that the address should be the same) - why wouldn't that work?

Comment: I'm not sure what the obsession is with "decimal" values - just put `0x804bd80` in eax and then both s1 and s2 should be pointing at the same string.

Comment: The previous step tries to ensure that what %eax passes a sscanf "%d" query, so it has to be one that is %d, I think. I've added that line to the code.

Comment: you need to learn to program in a high level language before taking on assembly

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Maybe if you explain what your end goal is, someone can help. As it stands, the question makes little sense.

Comment: If you pass two equal strings, in case and length, then `strncmp` will return zero, by definition.  A compiler may optimize the result to a condition code depending on the use of the return value.

Comment: The goal is to provide to strcmp a piece of data into `%eax` such that when it gets moved into `%esp` and passed to strcmp, it returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the return value of `strncmp` is zero for two strings that are the same in case and length.

Looking at your assembly code, the line:

```
test   %eax,%eax
```

is not part of the `strncmp` function.

Using a debugger, put a breakpoint at this instruction.  Examine the `EAX` register, it should be zero (depending if the `strncmp` function returns its result in the `EAX` register).

The `test` assembly instruction will set *condition codes* depending on the value of the parameters.  A popular *condition code* bit is the *zero* bit indicating an expression is zero.  The next instruction may be a *jump if condition code is zero*.

If you *use* the result of the `strncmp` function in a mathematical statement or expression, the compiler may generate different code.

Try this fragment:

```
  volatile int result = 0x55;
  volatile int a_value = 3;
  result = (strncmp("Hausaufgaben", "Hausaufgaben", 256) + 27) / 3;
  printf("Result is: %d\n", result);
```

Is there a reason you **need** the compiler to save the value from `strncmp`?

Is there a reason you **need** the compiler to compare the value to constant numeric zero?

Comment: The goal is to provide to strcmp a piece of data into %eax such that when it gets moved into %esp and passed to strcmp, it returns 0. The `test %eax, %eax` checks to see if the result form strcmp is 0 or not, and the goal for this particular project is for it to be 0.